# Can I prevent a shared layout for being used for error messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, view

I'm using a shared layout file, set up in _ViewStart.cshtml, for most of my site.  Something along the lines of:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

There is little to no information shared between most of my site, and the error reporting pages. How do I distinguish between the two situations?

I would like the shared layout to be loaded for all pages, except any error reporting ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the layout on a per page/view basis

```
@{
  var model = ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
  if (model is System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo) {
    Layout = "";
  } else {
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
  }
}
```

This is from my Post.vbhtml page - i just need to change the Layout page to use a different layout.

Comment: I just tried it - i changed the layout directive at the top of my post.vbhtml page and it used a different layout page.

Comment: That option provides a solution which *looks* right, but *behaves* incorrectly. I'm asking specifically to avoid loading the shared view. Not displaying it as a final result may be useful some of the time, but fails in subtle (and very important) ways for my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, this question has a a **popular, sometimes incorrect solution provided below. Choose with care, use accepted answer if unsure**.

---

There are **subtle** and **sometimes important** differences **between** the **accepted answer** and the **popular alternative below**. The alternative below leads to *a result which looks right most of the time, but doesn't always work*. This appears to be due to the load order and execution of view files - the topmost shared view is loaded and executed first. If that first load + execute process has side effects, this solution will break in strange and important ways.

_*ViewStart.cshtml*

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Instruct the appropriate views not to use a Layout, by adding the following to the top of the view files:

*ErrorView.cshtml*

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```